# Getting correct sign-in token for ArcGIS REST Service using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-rest-api, map-service, token

I would like to pull data from an ArcGIS Map Service, using Python (ArcPy/ArcGIS Pro), but I'm having trouble getting a token.

My guidance:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/getsignintoken.htm

This is my code:

```
import requests
import arcpy
url  = "https://...../arcgis/rest/services/..../MapServer/5"
head = {"Accept": "application/json"}
myFilter = "/query?where=1%3D1&&returnCountOnly=true&f=pjson"
token = arcpy.GetSigninToken()
if token is not None:
    try:
        theToken = token['token']
        theServiceUrl = url + myFilter +  "&token=" + theToken
        response = requests.post(theServiceUrl, headers=head)
        print (response.text)
    except:
        print ("failed")
        exit()
```

Produces this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 498,
  "message": "Invalid Token",
  "details": []
 }
}
```

So the system gave me the token to use, but says it's invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be straddling two different token objects. You can make an HTTPS request through Python or use ArcPy, but you need to follow the documentation for either.

Comment: OK....? I'm not sure I understand. Arcpy *is* python, no? It's just additional libraries specific to gis. In this code, I'm getting a token using arcpy, and then pushing it back to get the response.... Or not?

Comment: No, you aren't getting a token from the server. You are getting a token from the *Portal*. The code you have provided hides the URL of the server, but if it isn't the configured Portal, then it's not valid.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So I have the Portal, and the the ArcGIS REST Services Directory, and they are different. I want to login and get a token from the REST Services directory. Where do I find the documentation about those API endpoints to do that?

Comment: The documentation let me whip up a helper function -- https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/acquiring-arcgis-tokens.htm

Comment: @Vince if you make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as "Accepted". Hasn't solved my issue, but your explanation answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/) generates the token and keeps it as a property of the GIS object.

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "jskinner_CountySandbox", "*****")
token = gis._con.token
print(token)‍‍‍‍‍
```

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/get-the-token-using-arcgis-python-api/td-p/876344