# Getting token without providing credentials

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, token

In [Getting correct sign-in token for ArcGIS REST Service using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407410) I found that I was trying to use a token received from one source, on a different server, which didn't work.

Now I'm sure I'm staying with the same service, but I'm caught in a loop.

My "ArcGIS REST Services Directory" is located at `https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/rest/services` and looks like this in a web browser:

```
Home > services Help | API Reference
JSON | SOAP
Folder: /
Current Version: 10.71
...
```

So, now I try and acquire a token:

```
# create a session object
s = requests.Session()
  
# set username and password
s.auth = (username, password)

url = 'https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/tokens/generateToken'
response = s.post(url)
print ('RESPONSE: ' , end = '')
print (response) 

print ("\n")
print (response.text)
```

and get this:

```
     URL: https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/tokens/generateToken
RESPONSE: <Response [200]>

Invalid request <br>Usage: https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/tokens?request=gettoken&username=username&password=password&<br>Usage: https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/tokens/generateToken?username=username&password=password&<br>Usage: https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/tokens/gettoken.html<br>
```

As I understand it, I must supply credentials to acquire the token, which makes sense. So I use the instruction given in the failed response, and supply this:

```
URL: https://<server>.<domain>/arcgis/tokens/generateToken?username=_________&password=________
RESPONSE: <Response [405]>
```

which gets this:

```
Generate Token request should not contain username and password in the query string.
```

Answer (score 8):

If you think of HTTPS security as using a postal system, a `GET` uses a postcard, and a `POST` uses a security envelope. Unfortunately, to extend the metaphor, you've written the username and password on the front of the envelope in an "Attention:" block. What is needed is to place this information *inside* the envelope.

The mechanisms for doing this vary by language and library, but it seems that with `requests` in Python3, you need to include the optional `data` parameter in the request as a dictionary:

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://localhost:6443/arcgis/tokens/generateToken'

admUser = '#Redacted'
admPass = '#Redacted'
try:
    params = {  'f'           : 'json'    # {json,pjson,html}
              , 'username'    : admUser
              , 'password'    : admPass
              , 'client'      : 'requestip'
              , "expiration"  : '180'     # 3-Hour batch job
              }
    result = requests.post(url,data=params,verify=False)
    parsed = json.loads(result.text)
    print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))
    agsToken = parsed['token']
    
except SSLError as e:
    print(e)
```

returns:

```py
{
    "token": "seriouslyRedactedWallaWallaWashingtonPlusABunchOfTrashAndOnAndOn",
    "expires": 9999999999999
}
```