# How to gain access to password protected ArcGIS-Server WMS Mapservice

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, authentication

In ArcGIS Server 10.9 I have a password protected directory which has a map-service with wms capabilities. How can I now gain access to the WMS Service und GetCapabilities document? I tried using the "&user=xxx&password=XXX" arguments in the url,but the response has a status 499 - not authorized.

ArcGIS Server is using ADAP for it's user management.

Comment: I've never seen anything in ArcGIS* where you'd pass a username/password as query parameters to gain access. That's incredibly insecure. By ADAP do you mean Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA)? WMS is just a capability of the _service_, so I suspect this topic should hold true: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/accessing-arcgis-token-secured-web-services.htm

Comment: you should use a token that renews on an interval. The only real way to protect it is a proxy based approach https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/deploy/linux/using-a-reverse-proxy-server-with-arcgis-server.htm

Comment: I'm talking about the rights that can be set in ArcGIS-Server-Manager on a folder in the services directory. I have password protected the folder for certain users, but now I cannot get access to the wms service.

Comment: try using HTTP POST to pass your token

Comment: HTTP is inherently insecure; HTTPS is required, with the parameters URL-encoded in a POST DATA block (inside the envelope). See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408022/getting-token-without-providing-credentials

Comment: You need to generate a token and append it to the end of the request as token=